# React Hooks - keep arguments reference in state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, arguments, use-state

I created a hook to use a confirm dialog, this hook provides the properties to the component to use them like this:

```js
const { setIsDialogOpen, dialogProps } = useConfirmDialog({
  title: "Are you sure you want to delete this group?",
  text: "This process is not reversible.",
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      onPress: onDeleteGroup,
    },
  },
  width: "360px",
});
```

```js
<ConfirmDialog {...dialogProps} />
```

This works fine, but also I want to give the option to change these properties whenever is needed without declaring extra states in the component where is used and in order to achieve this what I did was to save these properties in a state inside the hook and this way provide another function to change them if needed before showing the dialog:

```js
interface IState {
  isDialogOpen: boolean;
  dialogProps: TDialogProps;
}

export const useConfirmDialog = (props?: TDialogProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IState>({
    isDialogOpen: false,
    dialogProps: {
      ...props,
    },
  });

  const setIsDialogOpen = (isOpen = true) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      isDialogOpen: isOpen,
    }));
  };

  // Change dialog props optionally before showing it
  const showConfirmDialog = (dialogProps?: TDialogProps) => {
    if (dialogProps) {
      const updatedProps = { ...state.dialogProps, ...dialogProps };

      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        dialogProps: updatedProps,
      }));
    }
    setIsDialogOpen(true);
  };

  return {
    setIsDialogOpen,
    showConfirmDialog,
    dialogProps: {
      isOpen: state.isDialogOpen,
      onClose: () => setIsDialogOpen(false),
      ...state.dialogProps,
    },
  };
};
```

But the problem here is the following:
Arguments are passed by reference so if I pass a function to the button (i.e onDeleteGroup) i will keep the function updated to its latest state to perform the correct deletion if a group id changes inside of it.
But as I'm saving the properties inside a state the reference is lost and now I only have the function with the state which it was declared at the beginning.
I tried to add an useEffect to update the hook state when arguments change but this is causing an infinite re render:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        dialogProps: props || {},
    }));
}, [props]);
```

I know I can call showConfirmDialog and pass the function to update the state with the latest function state but I'm looking for a way to just call the hook, declare the props and not touch the dialog props if isn't needed.
Any answer is welcome, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider not doing this, this is not a good coding pattern, this unnecessarily complicates your hook and can cause hard to debug problems. Also this goes against the "single source of truth" principle. I mean a situation like the following

```
const Component = ({title}: {title?: string}) => {
  const {showConfirmDialog} = useConfirmDialog({
    title,
    // ...
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    // Here you expect the title to be "title"
    if(something) showConfirmDialog()
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    // Here you expect the title to be "Foo bar?"
    if(somethingElse) showConfirmDialog({title: 'Foo bar?'})
  }, [])
  // But if the second dialog is opened, then the first, the title will be 
  // "Foo bar?" in both cases
}
```

So please think twice before implementing this, sometimes it's better to write a little more code but it will save you a lot debugging.

---

As for the answer, I would store the props in a ref and update them on every render somehow like this

```
/** Assign properties from obj2 to obj1 that are not already equal */
const assignChanged = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj1: T, obj2: Partial<T>, deleteExcess = true): T => {
  if(obj1 === obj2) return obj1
  
  const result = {...obj1}
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => {
    if(obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      result[key] = obj2[key]
    }
  })
  if(deleteExcess) {
    // Remove properties that are not present on obj2 but present on obj1
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => { 
      if(!obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) delete result[key]
    })
  }
  return result
}

const useConfirmDialog = (props) => {
  const localProps = useRef(props)
  localProps.current = assignChanged(localProps.current, props)

  const showConfirmDialog = (changedProps?: Partial<TDialogProps>) => {
    localProps.current = assignChanged(localProps.current, changedProps, false)
    // ...
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

This is in case you have some optional properties in `TDialogProps` and you want to accept `Partial` properties in `showConfirmDialog`. If this is not the case, you could simplify the logic a little by removing this `deleteExcess` part.

You see that it greatly complicates your code, and adds a performance overhead (although it's insignificant, considering you only have 4-5 fields in your dialog props), so I really recommend against doing this and just letting the caller of `useConfirmDialog` have its own state that it can change. Or maybe you could remove props from `useConfirmDialog` in the first place and force the user to always pass them to `showConfirmDialog`, although in this case this hook becomes kinda useless. Maybe you don't need this hook at all, if it only contains the logic that you have actually shown in the answer? It seems like pretty much the only thing it does is setting `isDialogOpen` to `true`/`false`. Whatever, it's your choice, but I think it's not the best idea